# How to define a variable of a class as class object in Python

Tags: python

I need to define a variable of a class a class object. How can I do it?

if for example I have a class like this :

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, a, b):
     self.a = a
     self.b = b
```

and I want to create another class B that have a variable as instance of class A like :

```
class B:
  def __init__(self, c = A(), d):
     self.c = c
     self.d = d
```

How can I do it ? I need to do particular operation or simply declarate c as object of class A when I create the object of class B ?

Comment: Do it in the function: `self.c = A()`. Default values are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it's called.

Comment: The code you have will create a single instance of A, and use that same instance as the default for every instance of B that you create.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Are you wanting to have an instance of `A` as a default argument to `B.__init__`?

Answer (score 2):

```
class B:
  def __init__(self, a, b, d):
     self.c = A(a, b)
     self.d = d
```

or

```
class B:
  def __init__(self, c, d):
     self.c = c
     self.d = d
```

or

```
class B:
  def __init__(self, d):
     self.c = A(a, b)      # a and b can be values
     self.d = d
```

Comment: Might need a little more explanation, especially on the last one (maybe provide some actual literals in there instead of using `a` and `b` which won't work since they haven't been defined).  The critical thing is that you can't just say `A()` because `A.__init__` requires two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote mostly works:

```
    def __init__(self, c = A(), d):
        self.c = c
```

But there's a "gotcha" which you *really* want to avoid.
The `A` constructor will be evaluated just once,
at `def` time, rather than each time you construct
a new `B` object.
That's typically not what a novice coder wants.
That signature mentions a mutable default arg,
something it's usually best to avoid,
if only to save future maintainers from
doing some frustrating debugging.

https://dollardhingra.com/blog/python-mutable-default-arguments/

https://towardsdatascience.com/python-pitfall-mutable-default-arguments-9385e8265422

Instead, phrase it this way:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, c = None, d):
        self.c = A(1, 2) if c is None else c
        ...
```

That way the `A` constructor will be evaluated afresh each time.
(Also, it would be good to supply both of `A`'s mandatory arguments.)

Comment: "That's not what you want" - I don't think you can say that for sure, it's really not clear from the question what the intention is.

Comment: `A()` will raise an error because it's missing the `a` and `b` arguments.

Comment: I would prefer  `if c is not None: self.c = c` to `self.c = c or ...`. If `c` can only be some class instance, which is normally True in boolean context, this will work ok, but more generally, it would prevent passing anything falsy for `c`, like 0, an empty string or list...